Newer high intensity (candela not lumens) lights for animal deterance
I saw the 7 year old post regarding "tactical" light to deter a bear. The post made sense for the flashlight technology of the time. [OP:  See LEP flashlights.  Is this the post to which you are referring?  Note that it is 3 years old, not 7.)
The evolution of handheld lights has made great strides since that post. The light intensity a pocket light can produce has increased from 500 to 1,000 candela to way more now. LED can now produce nearly 200,000 candela and a even a pocket flashlight can emit 69,000 candela.
Eyes get irritated around 12,000 candela and 40,000 becomes painful. [OP: can you provide a source for this?]  Moreover, with LEPs (LASER Excited Phosphors), not to be confused with LEDs (Light Emitting Diodes), the handheld size has been recorded to produce over 600,000 candela. And, not only is the intensity much higher, but the range is much longer.  While the modlite 69k candela light penetrates to about 400-500 meters, the LEP at the same size with over 600k candela, shines bright and true to 1200 meters (0.75 miles). [OP:  How much beam spread at this distance?  This will affect the brightness hitting the target.]  That is, this device could cause considerable eye-pain at a longer distance than you  normally would detect the approach of a bear or other marauder.
So my question is, based on the intensity it can produce, and the sensitivity of a bear's eyes, could a 69k candela modlite OKW or the even more powerful LEP (edc variants) [OP: What is EDC?] cause enough intensity to spook or deter a bear?  However, might the LEP device injure other animals or even hikers, and be environmentally indefensible in the wilderness?
What, if any, is the evidence from experience that these devices actually deter bears?  Consider that bears rely more on their nose and ears than their eyes.  Are there any regulations in the NPS or other wilderness areas against the "light pollution" of the extremely powerful LEP devices?

@Rory Alsop Can this Q be reopened now?  Or does reopening depend on the OP providing the links I asked for in the body of the Q?

Old question might be: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27737/is-it-worth-to-use-lep-flashlights-as-a-tactical-or-edc but it's only 3 years old, not 7. Seems to be at least a partial answer to the question.

Thankyou for the edit @ab2
